# How to Use ClassName for import the style of the Element react-js

Tags: reactjs

this is my component code

```
import React from 'react';
import Aux from '../../hoc/Aux';
import classes from  './Layout.css';
const layout = (props) => (
    <Aux>
        <div>toolbar, sideshow, backdrop</div>
        <main className = {classes.Content}>
            {props.children}
        </main>
    </Aux>
);

export default layout;
```

in this `{props.children}` just the `<p> Hi </p>` and this is my css file

```
.Content{
    margin: 2% auto;
}
```

thi
why the style of the `classes.Content` not working?

Comment: Are you using `create-react-app` to generate your project?

Comment: You cannot directly import css like. Change file name to this `layout.module.css`. Note  you need to add `module` keyword in filename. More you can read [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/)

Comment: Can you try using inline style to check if the style works? `<main style={{ margin: "2% auto" }}>`